# cannot get proper output when concat strings with variables using bash

Tags: bash

I have a simple script to read the content of a input file line by line with some extra strings added.  Here is one example.

input file: input.txt
content of this input.txt

```
aaaaaa
bbbbbb
cccccc
dddddd
eeeeee
```

code to read the file

```
    while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do
    echo "abc.def.hig.ewe.adg.hea.L_${line}.great"
    done < "$1"
```

I'm not sure where exactly it is wrong; I cannot get correct output. It looks like when you add `.great` at the end of a variable, the output will mess up the sequence.

Comment: What output do you get?  What output do you expect? I got five lines similar to `abc.def.hig.ewe.adg.hea.L_aaaaaa.great` using Bash 3.2.57 and Bash 4.3.

Comment: Is the data file from Windows or some other source that uses CRLF line endings?  That will make things look like:  `.greatf.hig.ewe.adg.hea.L_aaaaaa` instead of what I showed before.  And, I note, this would have been readily explicable (or discountable) if you'd only showed the output you were getting.

Comment: yes, you are right. the problem is the input file. it got corrupted when uploading from windows to unix. what a mistake. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Transferring comments into an answer.*</sup>

What output do you get? What output do you expect? I got five lines similar to:

```
abc.def.hig.ewe.adg.hea.L_aaaaaa.great
```

using Bash 3.2.57 and Bash 4.3 (on Mac OS X 10.11.5).

Is the data file from Windows or some other source that uses CRLF line endings? That will make things look like:

```
.greatf.hig.ewe.adg.hea.L_aaaaaa
```

instead of what I showed before. And, I note, this would have been readily explicable (or discountable) if you'd only showed the output you were getting.

> Yes, you are right. The problem is the input file. It got corrupted when uploading from Windows to Unix.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using something like awk? It is very good for these types of simple tasks.

```
$ cat input.txt
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

-

```
$ awk '{print "prefix_"$0"_suffix"}' input.txt
prefix_aaaa_suffix
prefix_bbbb_suffix
prefix_cccc_suffix
```

Comment: thanks victor. actually my problem is with sed -i.
i want to substitute a file content based on line number.
here is one example:

    sed -i "30s|^.*$|abc.def.acb.wet.hee.L_${line}.standard|" post_req.xml

however the output is always messed up, the standard always jump to the beginning of the line without any reason.